# Strtok outputting just a part of the string

Tags: c, string, strtok

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
  char name[] = "eseumdesconhecidolheoferecerflores.issoeimpulse.cities";
  char *str;
  printf("%s\n", name)
  str = strtok(name, ".cities");
  printf("%s\n", str);
  return 0;
}
```

This is the output:

```
eseumdesconhecidolheoferecerflores.issoeimpulse.cities
umd
```

I have no idea what is happening at all. What I want is for the output of strtok to be a pointer to `"eseumdesconhecidolheoferecerflores.issoeimpulse"`

Comment: Before answering the obvious (that's now how `strtok` works), [read the documentation of the function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok), then explain what you *expect* the output was supposed to be and why you think so once understand how the function works (assuming you actually read what I linked)

Comment: if you just want to strip off .cities then dont use strtok, its overkill.

Answer (score 4):

The delimiter argument to [strtok](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) is a string containing individual characters used to separate the string.

You specified delimiters `.`, `c`, `i`, `t`, `e`, and `s`.

So it's no surprise the output is `umd` for the first token, since it is surrounded by characters in your delimiter string.

If you want to find a whole string, you should use [`strstr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strstr) instead.

For example:

```
char name[] = "eseumdesconhecidolheoferecerflores.issoeimpulse.cities";
char *pos;

pos = strstr(name, ".cities");
if (pos)
{
    *pos = '\0';
    printf("%s\n", name);
}
```